# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[RouterModule -> Router -> Function -> Function ->Function]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Function

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]Recently I have started learning angular and in my first project I have been stuck on a problem occuring when I run the application with: ng serve.[image]

Comment: You don't need to add `Router` in `providers` as you have imported `RouterModule`. Remove `Router` from `providers`.

Comment: You are welcome, for a kindly reminder: for your upcoming question, post the code as a snippet instead of image. So it helps StackOverflow-ers for easier debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per attached screenshot try to remove `providers: [Router]`, Hopefully it will resolve your issue